# Code working in online code editor, but not locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a bit of code to increase the size of an image. I copy and pasted the code into a online w3 code editor and the code works as expected.
When I run the **exact** code locally in any web browser it does not work...

If I put any `alert()` inside it, it works, but the image size does not change at all.

Any idea why?

See the below snippet:

```js
function zoom(){
  var element = document.getElementById("myImg");
  var newHeight = 150;
  var newWidth = 450;
  var zoomStart = function(){
      element.width += 1;
      element.height += 1.5;
      if(element.height < newHeight){
          setTimeout(zoomStart, 10);
      }    
   }

  zoomStart();
  }
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="local_image.jpg">
<button onclick="zoom()">Try it</button>
```

EDIT:

It seems that if I set the image size in a separate css file, the image stops resizing. But if I use inline css to style the image it resizes properly...

Comment: Is the script inline in your html file... If so, make sure it is placed at the bottom right before the closing body tag. web langs are interpreted.

Comment: it works fineee